# Get post reactions for a public post in v2.11

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

Facebook released v2.11 this week with some changes to the APIs. According to the change log: /page/* — User information will not be included in GET responses for any objects owned by (on) a Page unless the request is made with a Page access token. Should this apply on the public posts as well?

Note that according to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.11/object/reactions, they are saying that permissions are usually not requested.

https://graph.facebook.com/{public_page_post_Id}/reactions is returning nothing in the latest version v2.11!

Comment: Yes, of course it does.